# I made a command that automatically responds to a specific message. The command works but it makes all my other commands not work (discord.py rewrite)

Tags: python, discord.py

This is the code that I use for command to respond when I say hello. This will work but if I try to use a command after none of them work, and if I take this out of my code then it works again. There are no error codes when I use a command. I'm really lost on how to fix this would anyone know why this is happening and if so how I could fix it?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL)
    hello = "hello"
    if message.content.count(hello) > 0:
        message = "Whats up!"
        await channel.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an `on_message` event, you need to `process_commands()` to allow your commands to work:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # checking against lower case string will be more consistent with finding more "hello"s
    if message.content.lower().count("hello") > 0:
        await message.channel.send("What's up!")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

---

**References:**

- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) - "If you choose to override the `on_message()` event, then you should invoke this coroutine as well."